# sets/number theory : no of occurences of a particular element in k subsets of n set

Tags: set

let there be a set S with n distinct elements namely a1, a2, a3, a4 and so on.

let the be subsets of S which have exactly k elements.

number of such subsets= (n choose k ) or nCk

out of all such subsets with exactly k number of elements, how many of them will contain a1?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, so I'm sorry if this is completely irrelevant now, but maybe it can help someone else.

In theory, consider that if we let a set P be S, but without the element a1, then P has n-1 elements. In this new set P, if we choose subsets with k-1 elements, then there will be a corresponding subset of S containing k elements, one of which is a1. So we're just using a set with one less element (n-1 elements) and choose k-1 elements for the subsets. Our formula is then: (n-1)C(k-1).